# What does the "J" means on MSI mobo overview components?

Tags: motherboard

Every manual of a MSI mobo has an overview of components indicated each of them with the corresponding name.
We can find something as *Processor*, *Socket*, *CPU fan*, but also some components where the first letter is **J** as:

1. JAUD
2. JCORSAIR
3. JUSB
4. JBAT
5. JFP
6. JRAINBOW

and so on and so forth.
So what that **J** mean?

Comment: Jumper?  Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3):

The "J" part is irrelevant to the component. It is a [Reference designator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator), specifically designating a connector jack.

To that end:

1. JAUD - jack/header for audio
2. JCORSAIR - jack/header for corsair fans, psu or lights?
3. JUSB - jack/header for USB
4. JBAT - jack/header for battery
5. JFP - jack/header for front panel lights/switches/etc.
6. JRAINBOW - jack/header for rainbow lighting

The letter "J" is commonly used in electronics to denote PCB mounted connectors. We would normally use numerical identifiers for each connector (J1, J2, etc) but it appears in this case they opted for descriptive names so that it is easy to see what each connector is for.

Comment: I originally voted to close this question, but due to this answer being a reasonable explanation, I retracted my vote.

Comment: I always thought J was an abbreviation for *Jumper*.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator That would normally be a "JPx" designator, but I have seen cases where it is a simple "J" as well. It depends a bit on the person doing the board at times.